# Why am I getting a segmentation fault when I run this code?

Tags: c

I'm learning the use of the switch statement and using the rand() and srand() functions  but then I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to run this code I got from this book I'm learning C from. What's could be causing this to happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int iRandomNum = 0;
srand(time());

iRandomNum = (rand() % 4) + 1;

printf("\nFortune Cookie - Chapter 3\n");

  switch (iRandomNum) {

   case 1:
      printf("\nYou will meet a new friend today.\n");
      break;
   case 2:
      printf("\nYou will enjoy a long and happy life.\n");
      break;
   case 3:
      printf("\nOpportunity knocks softly. Can you hear it?\n");
      break;
   case 4:
     printf("\nYou'll be financially rewarded for your good deeds.\n");
      break;

  } //end switch

printf("\nLucky lotto numbers: ");
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d\n", (rand() % 49) + 1);

} //end main function
```

Comment: Does anything appear on the console before the seg fault? Basically, do you get any of the printf statements to show?

Comment: Ensure you're [compiling with debugging flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) (usually `-g`) and then run your program using [`gdb`](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) to figure out exactly what line the seg fault is occurring on.

Comment: @adam nothing appears before the segmentation fault, I compile it with not errors, then when I run it, then it says segmentation fault.

Comment: You should be including `<stdlib.h>` (for `rand()` and `srand()`) and `<time.h>` (for `time()`).  Then you'd get compilation errors to prevent crashes from miscalling `time()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `time()` with no arguments.  The `time()` function takes one argument, and it's not optional.

Add

```
#include <time.h>
```

to the top of your source file, and change the `srand()` call to

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

**EDIT :**

You also need to add

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to get the declarations of `srand()` and `rand()`.

**EDIT 2:**

You can often (seemingly) get away with calling a function without `#include`ing the header in which it's declared.

In C90, if you call a function with no visible declaration, the compiler implicitly creates a declaration for it, *assuming* that the function returns `int` and takes the arguments given in the call.  Both `srand()` and `rand()` do in fact return `int` results, so calls to them could work.  But `time()` takes an argument of type `time_t*`, and returns a result of type `time_t`; a call with no declaration might work if you're "lucky", or it might blow up in your face.

The 1999 ISO C standard (C99) changed the rules, so calling a function without a visible declaration is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic from the compiler.

Even in C90 mode, most compilers can be persuaded to warn about undeclared functions if you give them the right options.

Bottom line: If you're going to call a library function, read its documentation (man page, whatever) and add a `#include` for the header that declares it.  And *don't* count on the compiler to remind you if you forget to do this.

Comment: you were correct, it was i didn't have #include <time.h> now it runs fine

Comment: thanks keith, wtf is wrong with this book, why isn't it showing me the proper methods, it was made in 2008, it's called "C for the absolute beginner".

Comment: but the only thing is i didn't use #include <stdlib.h> and it works just fine, is that normal?

Comment: @nastyn8: Sturgeon's law.  There are a distressing number of poor C books out there, written by authors who should know better.  (Herbert Schildt's books are notoriously inaccurate).  K&R2 is of course the classic book on C.  The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/)'s question 18.10 has some other good recommendations.

Comment: @nastyn8: Yes, that's normal, but you should still add the proper `#include` directives.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `time()` requires an argument, something the compiler would tell if you turned on all warnings, such as with `gcc -Wall -Wextra ...`.

The combination of not including `time.h` (meaning that `time()` gets a default prototype) and calling it without an argument is your specific problem.

The full list of problems found when using higehr warning levels are:

- `time()`, `srand()` and `rand()` have no prototypes, you need to `#include` both `stdlib.h` and `time.h`.
- `time()` requires an argument, like in `srand (time (0))`.
- you should return something from `main` (not strictly necessary in *very* recent iterations of the language but still good practice).

The following changes work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
    int iRandomNum = 0;
    srand (time (0));

    iRandomNum = (rand() % 4) + 1;

    printf("\nFortune Cookie - Chapter 3\n");

    switch (iRandomNum) {
        case 1:
            printf("\nYou will meet a new friend today.\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\nYou will enjoy a long and happy life.\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\nOpportunity knocks softly. Can you hear it?\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("\nYou'll be financially rewarded for your good deeds.\n");
            break;
    } //end switch

    printf("\nLucky lotto numbers: ");
    printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
    printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
    printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
    printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
    printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
    printf("%d\n", (rand() % 49) + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @nastyn8, it may still work but you won't have the prototypes for `rand` or `srand`. You should _always_ include the relevant header files for the functions you use.

Answer (score 3):

I used `gdb` to debug your code and your segfault happens at this line:

```
srand(time());
```

You are using `time()` incorrectly. You need to pass a parameter that will hold the resulting time, but `NULL` will cause the function to `return` the time:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Also, make sure to *always* `return` from the `main()` function.

This code works fine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

int iRandomNum = 0;
srand(time(NULL));

iRandomNum = (rand() % 4) + 1;

printf("\nFortune Cookie - Chapter 3\n");

  switch (iRandomNum) {

   case 1:
      printf("\nYou will meet a new friend today.\n");
      break;
   case 2:
      printf("\nYou will enjoy a long and happy life.\n");
      break;
   case 3:
      printf("\nOpportunity knocks softly. Can you hear it?\n");
      break;
   case 4:
     printf("\nYou'll be financially rewarded for your good deeds.\n");
      break;

  } //end switch

printf("\nLucky lotto numbers: ");
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d ", (rand() % 49) + 1);
printf("%d\n", (rand() % 49) + 1);

return 0;
} //end main function
```

Just in case you're interested in how I debugged your code, I compiled it with debugging symbols and every compiler warning possible:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra test.c -o test
```

And I started `gdb`:

```
gdb ./test
(gdb) run
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7ffba2c in time ()
(gdb) quit
```

Comment: i Did what you said and I'm still get seg fault

Comment: You still need to add `#include <time.h>` so the declaration of the `time()` function is visible.  And `#include <stdlib.h>` for `srand()` and `rand()`.

Comment: You sure? At first, I included it. But I omitted it and the code still compiled. I'll re-include it for good measure.

Comment: @nastyn8: Can you compile your program yourself and debug it? That above code works for me.

Comment: @nastyn8: Try including `time.h` for `time()` & `stdlib.h` for `srand()` & `rand()`. Any compiler warnings?

Comment: @Blender: Yes, I'm sure.  In C90, you can call a function with no visible declaration; it creates an implicit declaration and assumes it returns `int`.  In C99, this was dropped; calling a function without a visible declaration is a constraint violation.  Bump up your warning levels.

Comment: C99 allows you to fall off the end of `main()` like C++98 does, and the result is the same as `return(0);`.  I regard this as regrettable, and agree with your advice, but it should be qualified.